# Why MCU is not working without USB connected to PC

Tags: microcontroller, usb, cp2102

[image]

This my circuit of USB * CP2102, which i am using for PIC(18F6722) controller for USB communication (For Hex loading & USB Port communication).
My problem is after hex loading, microcontroller can not start without USB connected to my pc, microcontroller having its own different 3.3V & 5 VDC supply. also CP2102 having the different 3.3V rail.
Another problem is when i connect my usb to usb connector on board to PC, PC screen is flick for second.
If you found any wrong about circuit, please suggest me.

Comment: Does the program on the microcontroller rely on usb to start up?

Comment: @Bryan, No, its not dependent.

Comment: Is that the correct microcontroller part number? Searches for PIC16F6722 don't show many results and seem to suggest that it should be PIC18F6722. Also, the connections to the micro aren't shown. I suspect that the connections to the micro may have some bearing on any problems and it would possibly be helpful if they are shown. With a separate supply, I wonder if the micro is getting parasitic power from VBUS via the RX/TX.